# Setting variable in Swift with JSON

Tags: json, swift, swift5

so I updated my code right now and renamed some variables.
This is my code for requesting an JSON with Swift. My Project is called myTeam. I try to get some JSON Information and the problem is I guess that one variable in JSON is called Data. I try to get the name "A-League" and get still two errors:

Error 1 with the line in `self.parseJSON(weatherFile: safeFile)`
Cannot convert value of type 'Foundation.Data' to expected argument type 'myTeam.Data'

Error 2 with the line `let decodedFile =  try decoder.decode(WeatherFile.self, from: weatherFile)`
Cannot convert value of type 'myTeam.Data' to expected argument type 'Foundation.Data'

```
import Foundation
struct WeatherManager {
    
    //Link wird definiert
    let weatherURL = "https://api.soccersapi.com/v2.2/leagues/?user=submariner5&token=ca2b1a9b51062bbfae3415a0be991578&t=list"
    //Funktion macht aus Link + Eingabe einen ganzen Link und führt die Aktion performRequest durch
    func fetchWeather (cityName: String) {
        let urlString = "\(weatherURL)"
        perfromRequest(urlString: urlString)
    }
    // Funktion führt Request durch
    func perfromRequest(urlString: String)
    {
        //1.Url erstellen
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            //2. URLSession starten
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            //3. Give session a task
            let task =  session.dataTask(with: url) { (gettingInfo, response, error) in
                if error != nil{
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }
                
                if let safeFile = gettingInfo {
                    self.parseJSON(weatherFile: safeFile)
                }
            }
            //4. Start the task
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    //Das Ergebnis von oben wird hier ausgegeben
    func parseJSON(weatherFile: Data) {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do{
            let decodedFile =  try decoder.decode(WeatherFile.self, from: weatherFile)
            print(decodedFile.data[0].name)
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my Struct File.

```
import Foundation

struct WeatherFile: Decodable{
    let data: [Data]
}

struct Data: Decodable {
    let name: String
}
```

This is a part of the Json File.

```
{
"data": [
{
"id": "974",
"name": "A-League",
"is_cup": "0",
"is_amateur": "0",
"continent_id": "6",
"country_id": "14",
"current_season_id": "1082",
"current_round_id": "1022",
"current_stage_id": null
},
```

I solved it!!

I just had to change my struct name.

```
import Foundation

struct WeatherFile: Decodable{
    let data: [Anything]
}

struct Anything: Decodable {
    let name: String
}
```

Comment: How is 'myTeam' defined ? Is it a struct, a class ? In such case should be named MyTeam. Did you try to cast data: if let safeData = data as? myData (not sure it will work as I don't know how MyData is defined).

Comment: The next problem is that I dont find myTeam in the Code. I already searched with cmd+f. I just cant find the word in my code. Edit: it says myTeam is the Product Name.

Comment: What do you mean with MyData? I dont have that in my Code

Comment: Don't use built in type names for your own custom types, so rename `Data` to something else like WeatherDetails or something more relevant to the content.

Comment: Yes thats the aim. But I dont know how to do it. I did this with a tutorial and I dont know if the data she used is a variable or a swift function like URLsession. I changed weatherData and safeData to something else but still the same error.

Comment: In Xcode, command-click on Data and select Rename... from the menu.

Comment: ok i will rename every variable where is data written in it. I will reedit then my first post with the new code.

Comment: I renamed them now. There are still two Data types. But I guess they are part of a function from Xcode.

Comment: I solved it by my own yeahhh. Solution is in post. :)

Comment: @ahmetinho Actually Joakim gave you the solution an hour ago.

Comment: oh ok i gave you all upvotes for helping